# Scala: using recursion for an interest rate calculator

Tags: scala, recursion

I am attempting to use recursion on this interest rate calculator. Right now it prints the rate and monthly payments and things like that, but I want it to print the payment amounts and everything else for every month (not just the total) until the user does not have to pay an more. Is there a way to do that using recursion?

```
import io.StdIn._

println("Enter the house loan ammount: ")
val loan  = readInt()

println("Enter the number of years you want to take to pay off the loan: ")
val years = readInt()

println("Enter the annual interest rate")
val interestRate =  readInt()

val monthlyPayment = (loan*(interestRate/12))/(1-
(1+interestRate/12)^years*12)

val totalPayment = monthlyPayment*years*12

def monthlyPayment2(monthlyPayment:Int):Unit = {
 if (monthlyPayment>0){
  println(monthlyPayment)
 monthlyPayment2((loan*(interestRate/12))/(1-(1+interestRate/12)^years*12))
}
}
println ("The monthly payment is:"+monthlyPayment)
println("The total payment is:" + totalPayment)
```

Answer (score 0):

Monthly payment is the same every month (except, maybe the last one), so, if you know the amount, it's pretty trivial:

```
@tailrec
final def printMonthly(
  principal: Double, 
  amount: Double, 
  month: Int = 1
): Unit = {
  val paid = amount*(month-1)
  val left = principal - paid
  if(left <= amount) {
    println(s"$month: Payment: $left, Total: $principal, Remaining: 0")
  } else {
    println(
     s"$month: Payment: $amount, Total: ${paid + amount}, Remaining: ${left-amount}"
    )
    printMonthly(principal, amount, month+1)
  }
}
```